# Does a Pyromancy Apprentice with the Burn Everything Feat ignore Fire Immunity?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizard, damage-resistance

If a Wizard (Mage) who was apprenticed under the Pyromancy School also had the Burn Everything feat, would he ignore Fire Immunity?

Let me explain:
The **Pyromancy Apprentice** benefit allows you to ignore fire resistance. (I'm assuming that this doesn't include Immunity.)

> **Level 1 Pyromancy Apprentice**
>   You gain a +1 bonus to damager rolls with arcane fire attacks. This bonus increases to +2 at 11th level, and +3 at 21st level. Additionally, your attacks ignore fire resistance.

While the **Burn Everything** Feat allows you to ignore a certain amount of fire resistance, and **to treat fire immunity as resist fire 25**.

> **Burn Everything**
>   Your arcane fire powers ignore an amount of fire resistance equal to your Intelligence modifier. The fire resistance you ignore increases to 5 + your intelligence modifier at 11th level and to 10 + your intelligence modifier at 21st level. If the creature is immune to fire, instead treat that creature as having resist fire 25.

Combined together, would this allow a wizard to ignore Fire Immunity?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have actually looked into this before, and the answer is yes, they will be treating Fire Immunity as if it didn't exist. I have long wondered exactly why they decided to allow you to break certain character builds, and the teifling with fire damage is one of them.

it used to be that you could pick up some kind of weapon to just change all or most of your attacks to fire attacks, but apparently (according to JLan's comment) they errataed that out.

Comment: There aren't actually any fire conversion weapons/implements that cover all attacks anymore, due to errata (Flaming Weapon, for example, only covers untyped damage).  Hellfire Staff will convert Close Burst and Close Blast attacks, Burning Arc Ki Focus will convert melee attacks, and Incendiary Ring of Fireblazing (a Rare) will convert Basic Attacks.  Also, Weapon of Summer (heavy blades only, 15+) will add a +3 item bonus to attacks made with it, and that +3 is fire, so it would add fire to all of your attacks.

Comment: ah ok. personally I think it was smart to errata that. it happens to be one of the things that may well have needed it

Comment: Either way, Wizards have a very large selection of Fire spells. And if you use a Hellfire Cinderwand or a Flame Cinderwand, you can get some massive damage bonuses to all of your fire attacks.

Answer (score 5):

*Burn Everything* says "Fire Immunity is Fire Resistance" and *Level 1 Pyromancy Apprentice* says "Fire Resistance is irrelevant". So yes, as the rules are written, this combination completely negates fire immunity for all your arcane fire attacks.

Feel free to exploit.