# Does ignoring a Specific Resistance allow you to ignore Resist All when using that specific type?

Tags: dnd-4e, damage-resistance

Follow-up Question to [Does a Pyromancy Apprentice with the Burn Everything Feat ignore Fire Immunity?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73030/does-a-pyromancy-apprentice-with-the-burn-everything-feat-ignore-fire-immunity)

There are plenty of feats and benefits that characters can get that allow them to ignore resistance of a specific type. **Would this allow them to ignore a "resist all" resistance** (like the Petrified State, or a [Rimefire Plate](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=43)) **as long as they are dealing damage of this specific type?**

To give an example, if a Mage with the Pyromancy Apprentice Benefit where to use a fire power against someone who is petrified would the resistance apply?

> **Level 1 Pyromancy Apprentice**
>   You gain a +1 bonus to damager rolls with arcane fire attacks. This bonus increases to +2 at 11th level, and +3 at 21st level. *Additionally, your attacks ignore fire resistance.*

I can see it going one of two ways:

a) The Apprentice benefit would allow the Mage to ignore the fire resistance that is included in the resist all, so that it would become resist all except for fire.

or b) that the Apprentice benefit only applies to resistance that is *specifically* fire resistance, therefore, since the resistance isn't labelled specifically as fire resistance, the Mage would not ignore the resistance.

Optional question: Would this also apply to someone who ignores Immunity, attacking someone immune to all damage? (This might be irrelevant if there is nothing that is immune to all damage. If this is the case, le me know.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**

As you discussed in your option B, it explicitly lets you bypass fire resistance. Resist all is not resist fire + resist lightning + resist radiant + etc. It is straight up reduction of all damage. If you want to pierce resist all, you need an effect that explicitly allows you to do so (I'm wanting to say there are 1 or 2 effects that let you pierce resist all in special situations, like attacking objects or something).

Obviously the same is true for immunity: being able to ignore immunity to a specific damage type or keyword does not let you ignore immunity to all damage. I don't believe there are any published foes with immunity to all damage, but they could reasonably exist (presumably some sort of boss monster that you have to complete other steps to defeat).

Comment: Gloves of Piercing (PHB) have a daily power to ignore all resistance (up to 10) for one encounter, so you have means to bypass Resist all since the game release.